# How can I identify the text values that have the lowest row IDs across 4 columns?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, text

I found a few articles that are close, but not the same as what I am trying to do.  I have an Excel file that has 4 columns of duplicated data, each column is sorted based on a numeric value that came from a different worksheet.
I need to identify the 25(or so?) rows where the value of the four columns match, and the row ID is the lowest.  There will be roughly 250 rows of data to sift through, so I only really need the top 10%.
I don't HAVE to approach it this way.  I can dump this data into Access if this cannot be done in Excel.  Or I can assign columns next to each text column (a way of assigning IDs to each field in column 1, 2, 3, and 4) and use those values.  The approach is negotiable, as long as the outcome works.
Here's what my data looks like in Excel:

```
     A      B      C      D
    abc    bcd    abc    def
    cde    fgh    def    bcd
    def    def    bcd    abc
    bcd    hji    xyz    lmn
```

So in this case I would want to highlight (or somehow identify) the value "def" because it appears closest to the top of all 4 columns, hence it has the lowest row ID. The value "bcd" would be second on the list since it also is identified in all 4 and has a low row id.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I know SQL fairly well, so if you think dumping it in a DB would be best and you can suggest a query that would be awesome. But ideally... keeping it in Excel would be the least amount of work for me. I'm open to formulas, conditional formatting, etc.
Thanks!!

Comment: Please see my answer below for a request for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I **THINK** I came up with a fairly cool solution...

So, supposing you have this data in columns A-D, begining in cell A2, say.

Now, you know that you ONLY want values if they already exist in column A - Otherwise they're not in all 4 columns.

So:

- In E2, type in the formula `=Row()` - This basically says where A's value is located
- In F2, type in `=Match($A2,B:B,0)` - This will find the first match for A2's value in columns B
- Drag that formula across to G2 & H2 (to find the first match for A2's value in C & D respectively).
- In I2, type in the formula `=Sum(E2:H2)`

Now, drag E:H down for your entire dataset.

So, If H = `#N/A`, that means the values weren't in all 4 columns
And the lower the value for H, the lower the rank of the match - (Column A's text being the value you're matching for).

Now you could sort according to Column H, etc, to suit your needs.

Hope this does the trick (and makes sense)!

Cool Q, BTW!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have, or can you create, a master list of all of the possible cell values?  If so, then some simple VLOOKUPs on each of the 4 data columns could give, for each unique cell value, the row number in each column.  Add up the 4 reesults and sort on the total.

If you don't have the master list of unique values, I'd tend to go to Access because it's a pretty easy set of queries to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

### Clarification Needed

When I first came up with this answer I used the same approach that John used in his clever Excel answer, namely to use the sum of the minimum rows per column to produce the rank. That produces the sample result in the question, but consider the following modified test data:

```
F1   F2   F3   F4   RowNum
---  ---  ---  ---  ------
XXX  bar  baz  bat       1
foo  XXX  baz  bat       2
YYY  bar  XXX  bat       3
foo  YYY  baz  bat       4
foo  bar  YYY  bat       5
foo  bar  baz  YYY       6
foo  bar  baz  bat       7
foo  bar  baz  bat       8
foo  bar  baz  bat       9
foo  bar  baz  XXX      10
```

XXX appears in rows 1, 2, 3, and 10, so the sum would be 16. YYY appears in rows 3, 4, 5, and 6 so the sum would be 18. Ranking by sum would declare XXX the winner, even though if you started scanning for XXX from row 1 you would have to go all the way to row 10 to reach the last XXX, whereas if you started scanning for YYY from row 1 you would only have to go down to row 6 to reach the last YYY.

In this case should YYY actually be the winner?

---

*(original answer)*

The following code will import the Excel data into Access and add a [RowNum] column

```
Sub ImportExcelData()
On Error Resume Next  '' in case it doesn't already exist
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "ExcelData"
On Error GoTo 0
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ExcelData", "C:\Users\Gord\Documents\ExcelData.xlsx", False
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE ExcelData ADD COLUMN RowNum AUTOINCREMENT(1,1)", dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

So now we have an [ExcelData] table in Access like this

```
F1   F2   F3   F4   RowNum
---  ---  ---  ---  ------
abc  bcd  abc  def       1
cde  fgh  def  bcd       2
def  def  bcd  abc       3
bcd  hji  xyz  lmn       4
```

Let's create a saved query named `ExcelItems` in Access to string the entries out in a long "list"...

```
SELECT F1 AS Item, RowNum, 1 AS ColNum FROM ExcelData
UNION ALL
SELECT F2 AS Item, RowNum, 2 AS ColNum FROM ExcelData
UNION ALL
SELECT F3 AS Item, RowNum, 3 AS ColNum FROM ExcelData
UNION ALL
SELECT F4 AS Item, RowNum, 4 AS ColNum FROM ExcelData
```

...returning...

```
Item  RowNum  ColNum
----  ------  ------
abc        1       1
cde        2       1
def        3       1
bcd        4       1
bcd        1       2
fgh        2       2
def        3       2
hji        4       2
abc        1       3
def        2       3
bcd        3       3
xyz        4       3
def        1       4
bcd        2       4
abc        3       4
lmn        4       4
```

Now we can find the lowest RowNum where Item is found for each ColNum...

```
TRANSFORM Min(ExcelItems.[RowNum]) AS MinOfRowNum
SELECT ExcelItems.[Item]
FROM ExcelItems
GROUP BY ExcelItems.[Item]
PIVOT ExcelItems.[ColNum] In (1,2,3,4);
```

...returning...

```
Item  1  2  3  4
----  -  -  -  -
abc   1     1  3
bcd   4  1  3  2
cde   2         
def   3  3  2  1
fgh      2      
hji      4      
lmn            4
xyz         4
```

If we save that query as `ExcelItems_Crosstab` then we can use it to rank the items that appear in all four columns:

```
SELECT Item, [1]+[2]+[3]+[4] AS Rank
FROM ExcelItems_Crosstab
WHERE ([1]+[2]+[3]+[4]) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 2
```

...returning...

```
Item  Rank
----  ----
def      9
bcd     10
```